# Send A message with A different font with aTelegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a Telegram Messenger bot with framework *python-telegram-bot*!

Now, the bot must send a message with a specific font. This means the bot sends a message with a different and beautiful font - a font different from the Telegram Messenger font.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

No one (even you the official) can send messages in a different font/color, but you can make a suggestion to [@Telegram](https://twitter.com/telegram). They will consider adding this as a feature.

There have limited [formatting options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) in the message text, and you might like it.

Comment: Please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

These HTML tags are currently supported by Telegram:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

```
<b>bold</b>, <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>, <em>italic</em>
<u>underline</u>, <ins>underline</ins>
<s>strikethrough</s>, <strike>strikethrough</strike>, <del>strikethrough</del>
<b>bold <i>italic bold <s>italic bold strikethrough</s> <u>underline italic bold</u></i> bold</b>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
<pre><code class="language-python">pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language</code></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

The only color that you can use is red or set the background color to gray.

````
str = "`Hello`"     #this will turn the text red on Telegram.
str = "```Hello```" #this will turn the background color gray of the text on Telegram
````

Then at the **sendMessage** function, you need to add the parameter **parse_mode** and set it to **"Markdown"**.